# Replace regex match with string containing match

Tags: text-processing, files, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with text as

```
Afghanistan=+93
Albania=+355
Algeria=+213
American Samoa=+1
Andorra=+376
Angola=+244
```

It has all the country list and its dialing code.

I want to replace:

`Afghanistan=+93` with `Afghanistan(+93)=+93`

I can get the selection pattern as `=\+[0-9]*`, but what will be replacement pattern string?

I know of `\1` that is the captured match for selection but it don't seem to work for `sed`. So the regex needs to have selection.

How can I do that using sed or any other unix tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed 's/=\(+[0-9]\{1,3\}\)/(\1)=\1/'
```

To address your problem (as I understood):

Patterns that need to be memorized in `sed` are to be enclosed in parentheses - their appearance defines their index number.
E.g.:

```
sed 's/\(<memorized_pattern_1>\)<not_memorized>\(<memorized_pattern_2>\)/\2\1/'
```

would swap patterns 1 and 2 and delete the middle one.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Key i was missing was to put memorized pattern in parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Use that:

```
sed 's/=\(+[0-9]\+\)/(\1)=\1/' file
```

It searches for `=+` followed by at least one digit (`[0-9]\+`) and replaces all with the desired format (`(\1)=\1`).

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/=\([^= ]*\) *$/(\1)&/' <in >out
```

The above will just replace the last equals sign on a line and all characters which follow first with...

1. A copy of those that follow and which are *not* space surrounded by two parens *(in case there are any trailing spaces on a line)*
2. The whole matched pattern all over again.

On the right-hand-side *(the replacement field of the `s///`ubstitution)* `\1` represents the first `\(` grouped capture `\)` and `&` represents the entire matched pattern as a group. And so...

```sh
sed 's/=\([^= ]*\) *$/(\1)&/' <<\IN
    Afghanistan=+93
    Albania=+355
    Algeria=+213
    American Samoa=+1
    Andorra=+376
    Angola=+244
IN
```

---

```
    Afghanistan(+93)=+93
    Albania(+355)=+355
    Algeria(+213)=+213
    American Samoa(+1)=+1
    Andorra(+376)=+376
    Angola(+244)=+244
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose all the data is there in a file named as file, then

```
     awk -F "=" '{print $1"("$2")="$2}' file
```